# Ngnix + Drupal Image Styles not working

Tags: 8, media

I have a problem with different image styles (thumbnails etc.) not being generated when uploading an image using image field on a node. The original image gets uploaded and works normally, but other styles don't.I am having this issue with Drupal 8.

Comment: Have you found a solution? Are you sure its Nginx? Having the same setup and the same problem but i haven't thought of Nginx being the problem here.

Comment: yes it is of redirection in configuration file of ngnix that was causing the issue.I have just figured out this.But still working for the solution once I will get it I will post the same here.

Comment: I've fixed it for myself. I am using the configuration of perusio ([link to github](https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx)) but for some reason i had one important line commented out in my config and this was it. Even if its labeled for D7, i can confirm that with this configuration is working perfectly for D8.

Comment: I have also figured out the solution. It was image caching in ngnix conf that was calling in between the ngnix conf code.I commented that and placed that code in last of the ngnix.conf which done the trick for me.